# AsyncStorage setItem/getItem not working?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am using AsyncStorage to store and retrive some information (like name, email) in application. when i call setItem it returns the promise **"_45":0,"_65":0,"_55":null:"_75":null** and getItem also return the same. How do i set/get the value in AsyncStorage?
I am using the following code :

```js
export async function setItem(key, value) {
  try {
    var data = await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  } catch (error) {

  }
}

export async function getItem(key) {
  try {
    var item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
    if(item !== null) {
      return item;
    }
  } catch (error) {

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your function return promises. `async/await` is just a syntactic sugar. If you want to get item from `AsyncStorage` using your helper you need to use like that:

```
getItem('someKey')
  .then(val => console.log(val)
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

or

```
function async getItemAndDoSomething() {
  const item = await getItem('someKey')
  // do something with your item here
}

getItemAndDoSomething()
```

Comment: But it will return like the following **"_45":0,"_65":0,"_55":MyExpectedValue,"_75":null** . how can i access the  value  either i access by using **_55** or any other way is there?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of an `async` function is wrapped in a promise. Inside your `getItem`, you can access `item` as a standard object, but callers of `getItem` need to either (1) be an async function or (2) treat the return value as a Promise.